# Unable to Audit a table using triggers - Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, plsql

### Objective

I want to create a trigger, `audit_users` on table `Users`, which stores altering actions, old and new data in the table `users_audit`.

### DDL of Schemas

```sql
create table Users (
    username varchar2(30) not null constraint users_pk primary key,
    first_name varchar2(30) not null,
    last_name varchar2(30),
    age number not null
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE users_audit (
    new_first_name varchar2(30),
    old_first_name varchar2(30),
    new_last_name varchar2(30),
    old_last_name varchar2(30),
    new_age NUMBER,
    old_age NUMBER,
    action varchar2(30)
);
```

### Trigger

The following trigger gets successfully created

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_users
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON Users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
        INSERT INTO users_audit VALUES(
            :NEW.first_name, NULL, 
            :NEW.last_name, NULL,
            :NEW.age, NULL,
            'insert'
        );
    ELSIF UPDATING THEN
        INSERT INTO users_audit VALUES(
            :NEW.first_name, :OLD.first_name, 
            :NEW.last_name, :OLD.last_name,
            :NEW.age, :OLD.age,
            'update'
        );
    ELSIF DELETING THEN
        INSERT INTO users_audit VALUES(
            NULL, :OLD.first_name, 
            NULL, :OLD.last_name,
            NULL, :OLD.age,
            'delete'
        );
    END IF;
END;
/
```

### [ERROR] Performing Operations

I try running the following code

```sql
INSERT INTO Users VALUES ('jackie', 'Jackie', 'Chan', 60);
UPDATE Users SET age = 61 WHERE username = 'jackie';
DELETE FROM Users WHERE username = 'jackie';
```

But get the following error for each of the DML statememt

```bash
ORA-04098: trigger 'SQL_HMENLXODFUUNAEXBEDJCPFQUV.USERS_AUDIT' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

### Environment

Live SQL (Yeah! Sorry, I am just starting to learn)

### TL;DR

#### Tried

- creating a trigger that enters auditing data on table `users` in table `users_audit`
- running DML statements

#### Expected

- creation of new entries in the table `users_audit`

#### Actual Results

- error message received

Comment: Look for compilation errors: `select * from user_errors where name = 'AUDIT_USERS'`

Comment: this seems to work, https://dbfiddle.uk/W_Q42ux0 whitch version are you using?

Comment: If you're using liveSQL, post a link to your session so that we can see why your trigger isn't compiling correctly

Comment: I wouldn't spend time writing this myself. Check [this blog](https://connor-mcdonald.com/2020/08/04/level-up-your-audit-trigger-game/) by @Connor Mcdonald for a fullblown audit solution.

Comment: @nbk, I am using [live sql](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1000) running on oracle 19c

Comment: @JustinCave [Live SQL Session](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/kf7428cc2qxp7ob8twj9adwh)

Comment: The issue has seem to magically resolved on trying it again after 1 day?

I am still not sure how that happened.

Answer (score 1):

To make things a bit cleaner you may want to consider getting rid of the old columns in the audit table and use an action flag  (I=INSERT, U=UPDATE, D=DELETE).  See below.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

create table Users ( 
 username varchar2(30) not null constraint users_pk primary key,
 first_name varchar2(30) not null,
 last_name varchar2(30), 
 age number not null
 );

CREATE TABLE  users_audit
(   
    aud_who VARCHAR2 (30),
    aud_when DATE,
    aud_operation VARCHAR2(1),  
    username varchar2(30),
    first_name varchar2(30),
    last_name varchar2(30), 
    age number
    );
/

create or replace
   trigger users_aud_trg
    after insert or update or delete on users 
    for each row
    declare
      l_operation varchar2(1) :=
          case when updating then 'U'
               when deleting then 'D'
               else 'I' end;
   begin
     if updating or inserting then
         insert into users_audit
           (aud_who,
           aud_when,
           aud_operation,
            username,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            age)
         values    (sys_context('USERENV', 'OS_USER'),
           sysdate,
           l_operation,            
         :new.username,                             
         :new.first_name,
         :new.last_name,
         :new.age );
     else
         insert into users_audit
           (aud_who,
           aud_when,
           aud_operation, 
            username,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            age)
         values  (sys_context('USERENV', 'OS_USER'),
           sysdate,
           l_operation,             
          :old.username,
          :old.first_name,
          :old.last_name,
          :old.age);
     end if;
  end
users_aud_trg;
/

INSERT INTO USERS VALUES('ME', 'John', 'Doe', 37);
     
UPDATE USERS SET AGE=40;

DELETE USERS WHERE USERNAME ='ME';

SELECT * FROM users_audit;
```